# In Org-Mode Agenda view dont show "Scheduled: " if time is provided

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have setup org-mode and org-mode's agenda view almost exactly as I like it. 
Almost, because there is something I still find annoying:

Every scheduled item has a "`Scheduled:` " in front of it. To me, that is unnecessary clutter and destroys the alignment of my items. So what I want to accomplish is, that items, for which a time is provided (not only date) don't have the "`Scheduled:` " in front. Thus, they would perfectly align with those that don't have a time provided. Se the white square in my screenshot.
[image]

Is something like this possible? Alternatively I would like to remove the "`Scheduled:` " for all items, but keep the "Deadline: ".

My problem is that I am pretty new to emacs and org-mode and not proficient with lisp. So any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Ok,
the entry that needs to be modified is

```
(defcustom org-agenda-scheduled-leaders '("Scheduled: " "Sched.%2dx: ")
  "Text preceding scheduled items in the agenda view.
This is a list with two strings.  The first applies when the item is
scheduled on the current day.  The second applies when it has been scheduled
previously, it may contain a %d indicating that this is the nth time that
this item is scheduled, due to automatic rescheduling of unfinished items
for the following day.  So this number is one larger than the number of days
that passed since this item was scheduled first."
  :group 'org-agenda-line-format
  :version "24.4"
  :package-version '(Org . "8.0")
  :type '(list
      (string :tag "Scheduled today     ")
      (string :tag "Scheduled previously")))
```

from the org source code.
I can do this by adding

```
(setq org-agenda-scheduled-leaders '("" ""))
```

to my .emacs. sweet.

This gets rid of all the "Scheduled: " entrys. I still have not found a way to only remove those, for which a timestamp is provided.

Comment: The variable `org-agenda-prefix-format` controls whether to apply the `org-agenda-scheduled-leaders`.  See also the functions `org-compile-prefix-format` and `org-agenda-format-item`.